# Python: Input problems

Tags: python

I have this simple bit of code in visual studio using python

```
name = input("What is your name? ")

print (name)
```

However when I run it the string "What is your name" appears so I type in a name
then the code breaks and a red line appears under the last bracket and i'm told

NameError was unhandled by user code

```
name 'John' is not defined
```

I have no idea why this is happening i'm following a tutorial

https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-programming-with-python-8360

Comment: Most probably they are using Python 3 , whereas you are using Python 2.x .

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input()`, if you are using python2.x - `input()` in python2.x actually tries to evaluate the string you enter as a Python expression.